# How do I cut using the delimiter?

Tags: networking, command-line

Can someone help me to use cut command to remove daemon.warning below?

Jun 23 15:10:47 MC41241492 **daemon.warning** [vrrpd] VRRP:state_init
Jun 23 15:10:47 MC41241492 **daemon.warning** [vrrpd] VRRP ID 255 on eth0: we are now a backup

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Removing strings would be easier with sed, but if you want cut, then since you have variable length fields (date and time), you will need to use the "fields" instead of the "characters" in the cut.  Delimiting on the blank, that gives you:

```
cut -d" " -f1-4,6-11,13-
```

for the cut command, to be used in a pipe in this case.

Comment: Or use complement `cut -d" " --complement -f5 -`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The command above is working.